# Complex Excel Comparison

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets that look like below:

```
Date      |Ship To|Part Number|Quantity
----------|-------|-----------|--------
1/21/2016 | 1     | 1         | 200
1/26/2016 | 2     | 1         | 240
1/26/2016 | 1     | 2         | 750
1/26/2016 | 2     | 3         | 300
1/27/2016 | 1     | 1         | 150
```

I need a push in the right direction. One of the spreadsheets will be a previous version from a week earlier, the other spreadsheet will be a newly updated sheet. It is highly possible that past values may have changed on the new sheet and I need a method to compare them. because some entries (maybe 1 out of 200) may drop out and other (new) entries will be added, the two sheets will not be comparable row-row. I need a formula that will go into column E on the news sheet that takes a complete entry from the new sheet - date, part number, and ship to - and tries to find an entry that matches in the old sheet. If it finds a match, I need the quantity from the old sheet to display In column E next to the entry so that any differences can be noted.

Is this doable in excel? Challenge accepted anyone?

Comment: My attempt at a table didn't quite turn out. The columns are "Date, Ship To, Part Number, Quantity"

Comment: Here's a post I wrote about how I compare two sheets: http://yoursumbuddy.com/pivot-multiple-worksheets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=INDEX(OldSheet!D:D,MATCH(CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2),CONCATENATE(OldSheet!A:A,OldSheet!B:B,OldSheet!C:C),0))
```

Entered in `E2` as an Array Formula (Ctrl-Shift-Enter)

Comment: That could be a problem if on the same date there is a ship to of 12 and a part number of 1 and also a ship to of 1 and a part number of 21.  You should maybe use `CONCATENATE(A2,"|",B2,"|",C2)`